# Should I be using the Decimate modifier or Remesh modifier in order to simplify this model?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, retopology

I downloaded a free bust from Turbosquid that comes in STL format:

[image: Bust1]
[image: Bust2]

So I imported it and for obvious reasons it has over 2 million tris. I want to ultimately use it in architectural visualization scenes as a decoration, so I need to simplify the model drastically.

Should I be using the remesh modifier here, or the decimate modifier? I know they both have their place, but I'd like to know what would be the best for this kind of use-case.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Neither. In Object Data Properties, under Remesh, try the QuadriFlow Remesh. It's pretty amazing!

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a shot today! Thanks.